# Finding Lamé coefficients (scale factors) for the curves

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, coordinate-systems, curvilinear-coordinates

I am having trouble finding the Lamé coefficients for the following curves. I have specified all the necessary theory, however I am not sure how to practically compute it.
$$
\begin{cases} 
x = \frac{1}{2}(v_1^2 - v_2^2), & v_1 = \text{const} \\ 
y = v_1v_2, & v_2 = \text{const} 
\end{cases}
$$

Here is some background:
A point $P$ in $3$-D space (or its $\mathbf{r}$) can be defined using Cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$ by $\mathbf{r} = x \mathbf{e}_x + y\mathbf{e}_y + z\mathbf{e}_z$, where $\mathbf{e}_x,\mathbf{e}_y, \mathbf{e}_z$ are the standard basis vectors.

In the Cartesian system, the standard basis vectors can be derived from the derivative of the location of point $P$ with respect to the local coordinate
$$
\mathbf{e}_{x} = \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial x}; \quad
\mathbf{e}_{y} = \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial y}; \quad 
\mathbf{e}_{z} = \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial z}.
$$
Applying the same derivatives to the curvilinear system locally at point $P$ defines the natural basis vectors:
$$
\mathbf{h}_1 = \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial q^1}; \quad 
\mathbf{h}_2 = \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial q^2}; \quad 
\mathbf{h}_3 = \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial q^3}.
$$
we define the Lamé coefficients (after Gabriel Lamé) by
$$
h_1 = |\mathbf{h}_1|; \quad 
h_2 = |\mathbf{h}_2|; \quad 
h_3 = |\mathbf{h}_3|.
$$

---

**Additional note:** Lamé  coefficients are also known as scale factors.

Comment: Are you trying to study the change of coordinates $(u, v) \mapsto (x, y)$ given by the hyperbolas 
$$
\begin{cases} 
x = \tfrac12(u^2 - v^2) \\
y = uv, 
\end{cases}
$$
whose coordinate grid (lines $x = \text{const}$ and $y = \text{const}$) look like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gbwe8llwgr)?

Comment: By the way, it's best practice to use either all distinct symbols $(u, v), (x, y)$ for coordinates or all indexed $(q_1, q_2)$, $(r_1, r_2)$, rather than mix the two conventions.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thanks for the comment. To answer, I graphed these curves as $x=(1/2)a^2-1/2(y/a)^2$ and $x=1/2(y/b)^2-(1/2)b^2$, picking some value for $a$ and $b$. My professor said it is the correct method, so I guess this answers it. Now I just need to find the Lame coefficients, which I am still not sure how to compute.